# a ActionMessage EventTrigger for ItemDataTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have a question for ItemsControl.
If I wan't to Bind the Func Out of Items, like this:

Code:

```
  <Button cal:Action.TargetWithoutContext="{Binding MenuItemX}" >
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
    <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="Clicked" />
    </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
  </Button>
```

Link:([(Caliburn Micro) Mapping a ActionMessage Methodname to a Child Object of the ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6263039/caliburn-micro-mapping-a-actionmessage-methodname-to-a-child-object-of-the-vie)).
But I Bind the TreeView DataTemplate and use a Control MouseClick:

Code:

```
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate  x:Key="treeDataTemplate" DataType="{x:Type myData:Music}" ItemsSource="{Binding ChildNode}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" >
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                   <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                       <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="TreeItemClick" > 
                          <cal:Parameter Value="{Binding}" /> 
                       </cal:ActionMessage>
                   </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

The problem here is that the TextBlock(in Child ViewModel), the MethodName(in MainViewModel), and the Parameter(in Child ViewModel).
What's the best way to build it?

Comment: question is not clear

Comment: Just pay close attention to 【Code 2】，the EventName and the Parameter,sorry my bad english...